# Account Kit Instant Verification UI flow is glitchy when using CONTEMPORARY theme

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, account-kit

When using Account Kit's Instant Verification with the CONTEMPORARY theme, we are facing three UI issues when compared with the expected behavior in the [Account Kit documentation provided here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing#advanced)

1) On the screen that has the "Continue" button, the text says "Logging in...". However, according to the screenshots I have linked from Account Kit docs & according to an app on the play store called [Family Locator & Safety app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.familo.android&hl=en) (which also uses Instant Verification), we should instead see "Account verified". Displaying "Logging in..." incorrectly suggests to users that some work is currently in progress.

2) After you press "Continue", you briefly see a blank screen with the "Next" button visible. This button is not clickable. Once again, according to the Account Kit docs & Familonet app example, we should instead see "Logging in...", with the spinning throbber, and with no button in sight. Obviously, it is a bad UX to see an unclickable button flash before the user with a throbber-less blank screen...

Please refer to this brief [**Video Screen Capture reproducing the issue**](https://streamable.com/1rpgx) (also attached with this [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1223859834379818/) filed on FB support).

You can compare it to the demo screen recording that i have attached here to see the difference in functionality: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2016/12/20/introducing-instant-verification/

Any insight as to what might be causing this, and would fix this?

NOTE: We encounter this problem with the CLASSIC theme as well, with this difference: in Problem #2, we don't see the "Next" button, but the screen is still blank with no spinning throbber.

Comment: Do you have a question? This is not a place to report Facebook bugs

Comment: @WizKid "Any insight as to what might be causing this, and would fix this?"

Comment: Looks like this was filed as a bug to Facebook Developer support here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1223859834379818/

Comment: @OlgaKuznetsova yes. I filed that bug eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This glitch is an actual bug in the SDK. It has been [noted by the Facebook team, and will be fixed](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1223859834379818/) in the next release of the SDK

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the next release. :-)

Comment: Yes, hopefully :)